# Create a rest service to call and execute a postgres function

Tags: java, database, postgresql, rest, dao

I have a postgres function written currently called `do_function()`,  It does not return anything. I am creating a button on my web page that by pressing it will execute this function on the data base.

Is the following a good way to do this? I get an error: `No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111`

Currently I have in the RS:

```
  @GET
  @Path("/doFunction")
    public void doFunction(@Context HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        getDao().doFunction;
    }
```

In the DAO:

```
@Transactional
public void doFunction()
{
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
    SQLQuery query =   session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM do_function()");
    query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: [Ain't no such thing as "postgre".](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Identity_Guidelines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If when you say "does not return anything" you mean "returns void", many Java ORMs don't understand the void pseudo-type.

You might  be able to avoid confusing them by instead invoking:

```
SELECT do_function();
```

but otherwise, use a dummy result like:

```
SELECT 1 FROM do_function();
```

to avoid hurting the ORM's poor little brain.